# Having two different versions of the same post?

Tags: multi-language

I'm currently working on a site that's targeted for beginners in a new language. Now I'm looking for something that can ease my work with having two different versions of the same post. One "easy to read" and one with more adept language.

In the front end there should be some sort of option that let the user tab to which ever version he or she would want to read. Would be good if the user could set a default value in the user profile aswell.

Anything ring a bell?
I figure WPML would be worth a shot, but I haven't used it before, and I would like to try and find something else, since WPML also seems a little bit to advance for this purpose.

Comment: Even if WPML really seems to be a bit 'oversized' in its functionality for your problem, and I always think twice before I recommend a plugin: WPML is really one of those plugins which just works and has fair price / license. If you don't find a good alternative, give it a try and you won't regret it. I'm not part or being close to the WPML project at all, just a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that having two separate posts for the easy/adept versions is going to be hard to manage consistently, especially if you end up with alot of content.

It would be easier to use custom fields to store the two sets of information within the one 'post', then use javascript to toggle between which one is visible on the frontend.

Comment: Wonderful, How come I didn't think of that? :) Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think, as @Brad points out, Custom Fields would be the easy way to go.

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) is quite nice for this kind of situation.

Here's a screenshot of what can be achieved. I configured the fields to appear only if category equals "lingo" and to hide the regular content box.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try **[Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/)** which would allow you to directly connect the posts. On the front-end the user could just click the link to the more advanced or more basic post, back and forth.

The plugin provides some robust functionality, and you could even use it to display information about the connected post (such as comments).